# I want to speed up For loop in python and want to use less memory

Tags: python, apache-spark, group-by, azure-databricks

Hi below is the function i am using to calculate quantile(25/50/75) & mean for each column.

```
def newsummary(final_per,grp_lvl,col):
  new_col1='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['25%'])
  new_col2='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['50%'])
  new_col3='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['75%'])
  new_col4='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['mean'])
  final_per1=pd.DataFrame()
  
  final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.25).reset_index()
  final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col1}, inplace = True)
  final_per2[new_col1]=final_per1[new_col1].copy()
  
  final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.5).reset_index()
  final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col2}, inplace = True)
  final_per2[new_col2]=final_per1[new_col2].copy()

  final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.75).reset_index()
  final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col3}, inplace = True)
  final_per2[new_col3]=final_per1[new_col3].copy()

  final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].mean().reset_index()
  final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col4}, inplace = True)
  final_per2[new_col4]=final_per1[new_col4].copy()
  
  return final_per2
```

## Calling the function

```
grp_lvl=['ZIP_CODE', 'year']

for j in list_col:   # approximately 1400 columns to iterate
  per=newsummary(final_per,grp_lvl,j)
```

I want to find quantile(25/50/75) & mean for each column n retain that column in new dataframe. This i have to do for around 1400 columns.

The Dataframe are pandas dataframe.

While executing this loop .copy() command causing performance issues. Are there any alternate ways to reduce performance issues and not face out of memory error.
Your help & suggestion are appreciated.

** Note:- i am using Azure Databricks cluster to execute this. **

Comment: In place of `final_per1[new_col2].copy()` did you try `final_per1.select('new_copy2')`?

Comment: Its a pandas dataframe ...will df.select work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating 4 new columns for each of the column i.e., quantiles for 0.25, 205 0.75 and mean of the grouped data using pandas dataframe, the code that you are following might be a better choice.

- The pyspark grouped data requires an aggregate function and there is no aggregate function to calculate quantile.
- There is no need to use `copy` or return any value from the function. So, modify your code to the below code:

```
import pandas as pd
final_per2 = pd.DataFrame()
def newsummary(final_per,grp_lvl,col):
    new_col1='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['25%'])
    new_col2='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['50%'])
    new_col3='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['75%'])
    new_col4='_'.join([j]+grp_lvl+['mean'])
    final_per1=pd.DataFrame()
  
    final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.25).reset_index()
    final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col1}, inplace = True)
    final_per2[new_col1]=final_per1[new_col1]
  
    final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.5).reset_index()
    final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col2}, inplace = True)
    final_per2[new_col2]=final_per1[new_col2]

    final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].quantile(0.75).reset_index()
    final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col3}, inplace = True)
    final_per2[new_col3]=final_per1[new_col3]

    final_per1=final_per.groupby(grp_lvl)[j].mean().reset_index()
    final_per1.rename(columns = {j:new_col4}, inplace = True)
    final_per2[new_col4]=final_per1[new_col4]


for j in cols:   # approximately 1400 columns to iterate
    newsummary(pdf,grp_lvl,j)
final_per2
```

Comment: Hi Saideep, Thanks for the answer. Yes i have tried above code as well but AZ Databricks gives a performance warning " Your Dataframe is highly fragmented" & my cluster is crashing.  Hence i was hoping for a solution which si optimised.